# Auto update database SQL from excel file

Tags: php, sql, excel, laravel, synchronization

I have data in the form of excel files from a company where the file will always update with the system excel update to excel, how to make the data I have from excel can I save or sync automatically to SQL database without input manually.

microsoft give the tutorial from DB to Excel

this is the source

[DB to Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel)

but i need from Excel to DB

please help me

Comment: you have actual working functionality for excel o DB, what you need is  sync this time to time like cron job ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes u'r right..

Comment: Its an example in  laravel  task scheduling, where you can able to run your task time to time 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling
i hope it will help you

Comment: not working dude

Comment: can you paste your code so I can see what actually you are doing. is it possible ?